# How can you undo an SVN update in Eclipse with Subclipse?

Tags: eclipse, svn, subclipse

I just did an update on a team project and a few necessary files were not committed and now I can't do a build. How do I undo the last update so I can build again?

Answer (score 1):

You can do an "Update to Version" and update to the last working version of the source.